# Animate Bootstrap carousel caption

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I would like to animate the caption of Twitters Bootstrap carousel. In the caption I got a h1-Tag and four h4-Tags.

I want the h1 fade in first and after I want to fade in the h4-Tags. Before sliding to the next image, I want to fade out the h4-Tags and then the h1-Tag.

My slider.js:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    $("h1").fadeIn(2000);
});

$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $("h1").fadeOut(2000);
});
```

My HTML:

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://www.werkart-hannover.de/tl_files/images/projekte/neubau-einfamilienhaus-2.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Here is a test title</h1>
                <h4>Test</h4>
                <h4>Test</h4>
                <h4>Test</h4>
                <h4>Test</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.loth-haus.de/galerie/neubau_5232.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Here is a test title</h1>
                <h4>Test</h4>
                <h4>Test</h4>
                <h4>Test</h4>
                <h4>Test</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.loth-haus.de/galerie/neubau_5232.jpg" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Here is a test title</h1>
                <h4>Test</h4>
                <h4>Test</h4>
                <h4>Test</h4>
                <h4>Test</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Another problem is that my animation only works on the second slide.
How can I animate the elements inside the caption like I described?
Here is my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fh3o32y/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally got a solution!

I am only a beginner with Jquery, so I'm sure you can clean that bit up. Also, probably best to use your own Carousal Structure and just use the 2 classes for the captions you want to animate.

The trick is the use Animate.css but you have to disable the Ease function for Firefox on the animated captions, otherwise it causes issues.

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/z6xq12bh/4/

For more animation effects: http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

HTML:

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3 class="toggleHeading">Caption Text</h3>
              <p class="toggleCaption">This is some text<p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3 class="toggleHeading">Caption Text 2</h3>
               <p class="toggleCaption">This is some text<p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3 class="toggleHeading">Caption Text 3</h3>
               <p class="toggleCaption">This is some text<p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div> <!-- Carousel -->
```

JS:

```
    <script>
    var carouselContainer = $('.carousel');
    var slideInterval = 5000;

        function toggleH(){
            $('.toggleHeading').hide()
            var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleHeading').addClass('animated fadeInRight').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
                function (){
                $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInRight')});
        caption.slideToggle();
        }

        function toggleC(){
            $('.toggleCaption').hide()
            var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.toggleCaption').addClass('animated fadeInUp').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
                function (){
                $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInUp')
        });
        caption.slideToggle();
        }
    carouselContainer.carousel({
    interval: slideInterval, cycle: true, pause: "hover"})
    .on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleH).trigger('slide.bs.carousel')
    .on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', toggleC).trigger('slide.bs.carousel');
     </script>
```

CSS:

```
    .toggleHeading {
        animation-delay: 0.5s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
         -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
           -o-animation-delay: 0.5s;
           -moz-transition: none !important;
    }

    .toggleCaption {
        animation-delay: 1.5s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
         -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
           -o-animation-delay: 1.5s;
           -moz-transition: none !important;
    }
```